# Qlikview - Use selected value from listbox in another listbox

Tags: listbox, qlikview

I have two date fields I'm using in listboxes: DateCreated and DateCompleted.  This information is related to maintenance work order tasks.  When I select a date in the DateCreated listbox I have a text box with an expression which gives me all the new work orders for that date.  What I want to do is show all the completed work orders for the same date without having to select the same date from the DateCompleted list box.

Is there a way of having a generic input box so my users can enter a date and then this value is passed to both the date listboxes, or if  I select the date in the DateCreated list box the same value is automatically selected in the DateCompleted list box?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Can you please add your text box with that expression.

Comment: And I have a question: Is it true that you want to select the same date in DateCreated and DateCompleted?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got your point.

My test data is

```
LOAD * INLINE [
   DateCreated , DateCompleted , Task
   1.1.2014, 5.1.2014, AA Foo Bar
   2.3.2014, 17.4.2014, BB  Foo Bar
   7.3.2014, 7.3.2014, CC Yea
];
```

and I have three (simple) lists for DateCreated, DateCompleted and Task.

When selecting a Date in DateCreated the relevant values in DateCompleted are white, but if there are many you have to look for the same date.

So I decided to create a list with a *set analysis* as expression.

The formula is

```
=if(DateCompleted =DateCreated, DateCompleted)
```

and I named it SameDayCompleted. So this List only displays entries of DateCompleted that are also in DateCreated.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: SameDayComplete List]

It's not exactly what you ask for, but maybe that helps.